# Zoom Image .asset flutter

Tags: imagen, flutter, zoom

Buen dia. trato de poner Zoom image (photoview) en el imageAsset, pero todos los tutoriales mencionan que debo colocar a la asset.imagen asi: 
  "child: PhotoView(imageProvider: AssetImage("assets/large-image.jpg")"". Esta es parte del código de mi dart:

```
class DetailsPageBody extends StatefulWidget {
final Book bookObject;

DetailsPageBody(this.bookObject);

@override
_DetailsPageBodyState createState() =>    _DetailsPageBodyState();
}

class _DetailsPageBodyState extends State<DetailsPageBody> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TopContainer(widget: widget),
              AuthorContainer(widget: widget),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 43),
                child: GenreContainer(widget: widget),
              ),
              TabBarContainer(widget: widget),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 25,
            top: 20,
            child: Container(
              height: 260,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 30,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                child: Image.asset(widget.bookObject.cover,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

La cuestión es que no logro que tenga lógica o me funcione  lo de "image provider" ¿como deberia colocar o rearreglar esta lineas de mi código "child: Image.asset(widget.bookObject.cover,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain)," siquiera hacerle zoom a este objeto-imagen?.

Ya importé la dependencia y el paquete de photoview, pero no logro implmentarlos.

Comment: intentas poner en lugar de Image.asset(widget.bookObject.cover,
                    fit: BoxFit.contain),  estoo ->  , PhotoView(
      imageProvider: AssetImage(widget.bookObject.cover),
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, tienes una **EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY**, a mi entender esto puede ser causado por que el Stack widget no tiene ningún tamaño como referencia de parte de su padre ListView. Esto se puede solucionar al envolver el Stack widget con un `SizedBox` (height, width).

Implementando el PhotoView quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 500,
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                       TopContainer(widget: widget),
                       AuthorContainer(widget: widget),
                       Padding(
                         padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 43),
                         child: GenreContainer(widget: widget),
                       ),
                       TabBarContainer(widget: widget),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    left: 25,
                    top: 20,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 260,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 30,
                      child: PhotoView(
                        imageProvider: AssetImage(
                          widget.bookObject.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```